# Set up a global variable I can use throughout my package

Tags: python, package, global-variables

I am trying to set a global variable I can use inside my whole package, but there's something I don't understand and I didn't find a similar question.

Here is the content of `config.py`

```
var = 1
```

Here is the content of `a.py`

```
from config import var

def function1():
    global var 
    print(var)
    var = 2
```

Here is the content of `b.py`

```
from a import function1
from config import var

function1()

def function2():
    global var
    print(var)

function2()
```

This is probably very silly, but I would be interested to have output 1 and 2, but both functions, i.e. `function1()` and `function2()`, give me output 1

How can I set a variable I can use throughout my package? Is it a good practice?

Comment: Never use a `from` import for anything you plan to assign to.

Comment: `import config` then `config.var = 2`

Comment: It would be nice to have a bit more details about that.